# export python and tensorflow model for android

Tags: python, android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

in the past days I built a python script which is doing following thing:

- load an own created CNN model
- define a function where a WAV file is loaded and converted to a spectrogram
- define another function where this generated spectrogram is saved as PNG image
- record microphone input for 3 seconds and save it as a WAV file
- call the two funtions and pass the spectrogram image to the CNN model
- let the model predict the class and print the result somewhere

And what I now want is to export this whole script to an android smartphone so that on the smartphone the microphone input is taken as input. and the predicted result shall be displayed somewhere on the phone.

**How can I export / convert this whole script to an android-usable format?**

I already tried to convert the script to TFlite and import it to android studio. But then it wants an image and not a WAV file.

please help